# Align text to 3 edges in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure

```css
body{
    max-width: 943.61px;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<body>
<div class="home">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <span class="about-me">Python</span>
    <span class="language">RU|ENG</span>
</div>
</body>
```

How can I align `name` to the left, `about_me` to center, and `language` to the right of the parent tag?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `.home` into a flex container and set `justify-content: space-between`. This makes it so that the children is distributed along the length of the flexbox in the flex direction.

```css
.home {
  /* just for demo */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;


  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="home">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <span class="about-me">Python</span>
    <span class="language">RU|ENG</span>
</div>
</body>
```

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good resource on how to use flex in css.

Comment: note: `flex-direction: row` is redundant and not needed as it is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution with flexbox and text-align (just to be different from @cSharp)

```css
body {
    max-width: 943.61px;
}

.home {
    display: flex;
}

span {
    flex: 1;
}

.about-me {
    text-align: center;
}

.language {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="home">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <span class="about-me">Python</span>
    <span class="language">RU|ENG</span>
</div>
</body>
```